# Apache couldn't determine servername on docker container

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set up a customized docker container for an existing site. To do so I want to provide my own custom `vhost` configuration with a `ServerName`.

But when I try to add a custom `vhost configuration` and restart apache I get the warning that Apache was unable to determine the global name: `Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.26.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

What's important is the fact that when I log into container's shell and manually run `service apache2 restart` I do not get this warning anymore.

How can I suppress that on the build? Should I provide the `vhost` to the composer somehow else?

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` is like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./etc/php
      args:
         - APP_HOST=${APP_HOST}
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:80
      - ${APP_PORT_SSL}:443
    volumes:
      - ./var/bin/:/tmp/bin/
      - ./app/:/var/www/html/
      - ./log/:/var/log/
      - ./etc/php/conf/:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${VIRTUAL_HOST}
```

Then, `Dockerfile` that adds my own available site:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
ENV TERM=xterm
LABEL maintainer="Derek P Sifford <dereksifford@gmail.com>" \
      version="0.15.2-php7.0"

ARG APP_HOST
ENV APP_HOST=$APP_HOST

ADD ./sites/app.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/app.conf
RUN sed -i 's/ServerName APP_HOST/ServerName '$APP_HOST'/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/app.conf

RUN sed -i 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf \
    && a2enmod rewrite expires \
    && a2dissite 000-default.conf \
    && a2ensite app.conf \
    && service apache2 restart

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80 443
```

And obviously site config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName APP_HOST

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/apache-error-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-n/256018#256018) and in the warning message you can set the `ServerName` property to `localhost` in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` from within the Dockerfile.

Comment: Solved by adding `echo "ServerName localhost" | tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf && \
    a2enconf fqdn ` to Dockerfile. Thanks :)

Comment: I added `RUN echo "ServerName localhost" | tee -a /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` to the Dockerfile. Thank you @TomaszKapłoński and @yamenk!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your configuration, because you copy it and mount it on a volume. I think your configuration should not evolve when your container is live, so you don't need to mount it.

So, try to remove this line from your docker-compose.yml :

```
- ./etc/php/conf/:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
```

Comment: I have some changes to default php configuration (stuff like max file upload) there... how can I modify it otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

On your apache container instance, you should put IP `172.26.0.2` in  `/etc/hosts` and provide a fully qualified name to it e.g.

> 172.26.0.2  vbox.test.com

Then replace hostname with vbox.test.com

or

put `localhost`  in serverName.

[This](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CouldNotDetermineServerName)  should help you.