# why dockerfile can't start db with " CMD /etc/init.d/mysql start "?

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, dockerfile

I downloaded a docker image with mariadb and phpmyadmin,
then wrote two dockerfiles below..

```
# dockerfile A
FROM alfvenjohn/raspbian-buster-mariadb-phpmyadmin

CMD /etc/init.d/mysql start && /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

```
# dockerfile B
FROM alfvenjohn/raspbian-buster-mariadb-phpmyadmin

CMD service mysql start && /usr/sbin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

dockerfile B worked well,

but dockerfile A failed.

I can build image from dockerfileA,

then spin-up container from it `docker run -it -p 80:80 <img id> bash`

the container up successfully,

but while I inside the container, I found the services of mariadb and apache2 not working.

After I execute `/etc/init.d/mysql start && /etc/init.d/apache2 start`,

mariadb and apache2 works!

***Trying to get error messages by `docker logs <container id>`, but got nothing.***

What my question is

"If I run the docker image without dockerfile just by commands,

like what I did in dockerfile A. The container works well. "

```
$ docker run -it -p 80:80 alfvenjohn/raspbian-buster-mariadb-phpmyadmin bash
$ /etc/init.d/mysql start && /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Why? Didn't dockerfile A do the same thing, as I spin up my container with commands ?

Comment: Please give mode details about dockerfile A failed. Is the container able to start ? Is there any error in the logs.

Comment: Sorry Mr. Cyril, and thank you for remind. I build image with dockerfileA successfully, then I start the container with `$ docker run -it -p 80:80 <img id> bash`. In the container I found mysql and apache2 didn't start, If I execute `$ /etc/init.d/mysql start && /etc/init.d/apache2 start`, this two services start successfully.  I tried to check the error message with `$ docker logs <container id>`, but nothing showed.

Comment: You need to remove the bash at this end of the command. This replace the command inside your dockerfile. docker run -d -p 80:80 <img id>. You can use docker exec -it <container_id> bash if you want to connect inside the container afterward

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the bash at this end of the command. This replace the command inside your dockerfile.

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 <img id>
```

You can use this command to connect inside the container afterward:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> bash
```

Comment: Mr. Cyril. I ran`docker run -d -p 80:80 <dockerfileA img id>`, the container A up for few seconds, then exited. I checked error logs with `docker logs <container A>`, It shows `[ ok ] Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . ..
[....] Starting Apache httpd web server: apache2AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
. ok`, but while I ran `docker run -d -p 80:80 <dockerfileB img id>`, the container B and serves in it worked well.

Comment: You are not using an Docker official image, it is hard to say how the initial image is built. You can check this article to configure your apache: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47864581/apache-couldnt-determine-servername-on-docker-container

Comment: Thank you for the advice Mr. Cyril, I will keep working for it.

Answer (score 1):

A Docker image runs a single command only.  When that command exits, the container exits too.

This combination usually means a container runs a *single* server-type process (so run MySQL and Apache in separate containers), and it means the process must run in the foreground (so the lifetime of the container is the lifetime of the server process).

In your setup where you launch an interactive shell instead of the image `CMD`, you say you can start the servers by running

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start && /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

This is true, **and then you get a command prompt back**.  That means the command completed.  If you run this as an image's `CMD` then "you get a command prompt back" or "the command completed" means "the container will exit".

Generally you want to launch separate database and Web server containers; if you have other application containers you can add those to the mix too.  Docker Compose is a common tool for this.  You may want to look through Docker's [sample applications](https://docs.docker.com/samples/) for some examples, or other SO questions.