# Configuring SSL with apache server in a docker container

Tags: docker, apache, ssl, docker-compose

I am setting up a LAMP app in a docker container hosted in ubuntu. I am a docker noob

I generated the CSR on the server that is hosting the docker container that has the public IP and domain i am using.

In my Docker file I have

```
COPY ./dev.key /etc/apache2/ssl/dev.key
COPY ./dev.combined /etc/apache2/ssl/dev.combined
```

Then in the apache.conf i have

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/dev.combined
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/dev.key

  ServerAdmin admin@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is when i try to start apache I get the error:

> AH02565: Certificate and private key 127.0.0.1:443:0
> from /etc/apache2/ssl/dev.combined and /etc/apache2/ssl/dev.key do not
> match AH00016: Configuration Failed

There is something i am not understanding in configuring this docker image.

The Domain has a real public IP , so the CSR and Cert need to point to this IP.

Am I setting up something incorrectly in Docker so it thinks it is running 127.0.0.1 and not the IP i need?

Thanks for any help. I am in way over my head.

Comment: what is dev.combined? your key should be paired with a certificate

Comment: @richardsefton the dev.combined is the cert as well as the the CA Bundle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47864581/apache-couldnt-determine-servername-on-docker-container/47865297, that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I was close. I had to make a couple of changes

```
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/dev.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/dev.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/dev.ca-bundle
```

But the thing that fixed the 'Certificate and private' error..
I had to add my domain in my /etc/host on the server that hosted the docker

```
127.0.0.1 mydomain.dev localhost
```